# Display only the columns of two different select statements containing one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two select statements which both have one row but an fixed number of columns (15).

So far I have tried using `intersect` but it doesn't seem to do what I want

```
select 'ABC' as test, 'DEF' as test2, '123' as test3

select 'ABC2' as test, 'DEF' as test2, '124' as test3
```

Comparing both will display the a string will the differences

The result will the the columns with the different values as a string. In this case:

```
"'test': 'ABC', 'test3': '123'"
```

Comment: A `SELECT` statement must first be well defined, so it *can't* have an unknown number of columns. In your example, they explicitly have 2 columns, and can *only* return 2 columns.

Comment: I have assumed you are using SQL Server here, based on the [[tag:tsql]] tag, and thus tagged [[tag:sql-server]]. If you aren't using SQL Server, and are using a different product that uses T-SQL, such as Azure SQL Edge, Azure Synapse, Sybase, etc, then please [edit] your post to correct the tag(s).

Comment: There isn't a unknown number of columns but a fixed number but both columns will have the same number of columns always

Comment: So what are you asking here exactly? What are your expected results of the above 2 queries?

Comment: It will display a single column called test and the value ABC. that is all the different values

Comment: Please edit the quetion and include the expected.

Comment: Please explain the logic of why it's only displaying the first value? And if you only want the first value, just select the first value and remove the second select.

Comment: I am triyng to compare both select statements to get the different values. because 'ABC' != 'ABC2' in the column test it will display that. but 'DEF' is the same value in test2

Comment: `SELECT 'ABC' AS test EXCEPT SELECT 'ABC2' AS test;`?

Comment: As already stated though, you must return a static number of columns, therefore if you want to compare 2 columns, you must always return 2 columns .

Comment: But I need to check test2 as well. 
select 'ABC' as test, 'DEF' as test2 EXCEPT select 'ABC2' as test, 'DEF' as test2 still returns DEF

Comment: And your scenario seems like it might be a bit simplistic, is there only ever 2 rows? And you always want the value from the first row if it's different to the value in the second row?

Comment: To compare 2 columns you'll have to return something for the second column, even if null.

Comment: There will be about 10+ columns that will need to be compared

Comment: Based on the comments above, please clarify your question to handle more columns that are different, and knowing you have to return a static number of columns. And clarify that there is only ever 2 rows

Comment: As already said, You you can't return a variable number of columns, if you are comparing 11 columns, you need 11 columns in your results, or a single column with comma separated value's - maybe that is what you mean?

Comment: ok, because it can't be columns I will make it a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bunch of case expressions to compare each column and output a value if different e.g.

```
select
  case when a.test1 <> b.test1 then 'test1:' + a.test1 else '' end
  + case when a.test2 <> b.test2 then ', test2:' + a.test2 else '' end
  + case when a.test3 <> b.test3 then ', test3:' + a.test3 else '' end
from (
    select 'ABC' as test1, 'DEF' as test2, '123' as test3
) a
cross join (
  select 'ABC2' as test1, 'DEF' as test2, '124' as test3
) b;
```

Returns:

| Result |
| --- |
| test1:ABC, test3:123 |

Comment: This get the job done. I find it quite slow thought, with 15 cases it takes about 3-5 seconds

Comment: Thats down to the indexes you have on your table...